# iOS Swift Text Fill Screen

Tags: ios, uiview, label

I have taken a label and dragged it onto a blank UIView.

I have changed the text orientation with

```
codeLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

but I now want the text to fill the screen, I have browsed the web and found this but it doesnt seem to work

```
codeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a width equal constraint between the UILabel and its parent UIView. Do that by draging from the UILabel to the UIView.

What you want to achieve is to let the UILabel with equals to the UIView height. but what you have so far is an equal widths constraint.

Select that constraint by clicking it and change the value next to "Second Item" to Superview.Height.

To let font fit the screen:

1. select the label.
2. set a very large font. example 100.
3. change the value of Autoshrink to Minimum font size.
4. set a small value there. example 5.

Comment: I am able to get the label to fill the screen, but I cannot get the text to then fill the label.

Comment: so you used my solutoin and that what happen?

Comment: What do you mean by dragging from the UIlabel to the UIView, did u mean ctrl+drag?

Comment: to add a constraint ctrl+click the label and then move curser to uiview and release.

Comment: I have done this, now the label is completely missing from the screen

Comment: in the interface builder or after you run the app?

Comment: what constraint do you have? other than the one I suggested?

Comment: remove all keep left and top constraints

Comment: Aspect Ratio Constraint: firstitem=codeLabel.Height, seconditem=SupverView.Width

Comment: this is the one I suggested. it should be the way around. firstitem=codeLabel.Width, seconditem=SupverView.Height

Comment: I have done this, and added a constraint to the top-left.  I see the label, but it runs off the screen

Comment: OK, lets simplify this.  I get the label to fill the screeen.  Now how do I get the text to fill the label?